# What happens to your items if someone kills you with a crossbow?

Tags: werewolv.es

Do they take your items, or do you go to the graveyard with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items always go to the killer, this also applies to crossbows.

In your described scenario, the items would fall into the hands of the player who used the crossbow.